# Why does the following example not compile on clang

Tags: c++, clang

```
template<class ...Args>
using Fn = int(*)(Args... args);

template<class ...Args>
void CreateHandler(const Fn<Args...> ) {

}

int my_fun() {
    return 1;
}

void CreateGenericHandler() {
    Fn<> s = & my_fun;
    CreateHandler<>(s);
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

gives the following compile error

```
main.cpp:19:5: error: no matching function for 
call to 'CreateHandler'
     CreateHandler<>(s);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
 ../template_bug_testing/main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: > failed template argument deduction void
 CreateHandler(const Fn<Args...> ) {
```

and is built with command

```
clang++ -c -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -W -fPIC
```

where clang version info is

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.16.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode- beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

but this error does not occur on msvc or gcc.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0mYxvu2Qc5BCHBKm

Comment: Looks like a clang bug to me.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Clang 3.9.1, GCC 7 or CL 19 RC.

Comment: can reproduce on clang  3.8.0 (and 3.8.1) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b9a7a5cd6c77039

Comment: Maybe Apple broke their llvm/clang once more, that's not too uncommon.

Comment: Here is another reproduction: http://rextester.com/QEKW7177